# How to get status code when using after_request?

Tags: python, logging, flask

How to get the *status code* (200, 500, ... ) when using *after_request* ?

What I want is to have the kind of output we have with a logger (for example werkzeug) but where it's possible to add what I want (username, ...) :

*remote_IP, timepoint, path, status_code*

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The function(s) that are registered to run after each request should take a response class object and return a response class object (see http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.Flask.after_request)

So you can take that info from the response class object, for more info on what is available see http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.Response

Here is a partial example:

```
import logging

#
# your other flask code here
#

@app.after_request
def log_the_status_code(response):
    status_as_string = response.status
    status_as_integer = response.status_code
    logging.warning("status as string %s" % status_as_string)
    logging.warning("status as integer %s" % status_as_integer)
    return response
```

and as output, you should get in the console after a successful hit:

```
WARNING:root:status as string 200 OK
WARNING:root:status as integer 200
```

Comment: Make sure you take note of "return response" at the end of this function, unlike me who spent an hour googling "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'headers'".